# Begin Transaction e Save Transaction SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transações

Tenho uma StoredProcedure em um sistema que estou trabalhando e tenho o seguinte código

```
begin transaction;
save transaction Integration_SP;
-- CODIGO
commit transaction;
```

Estive buscando e só encontrei comparações entre BEGIN e SAVE transaction, não entendi o porque aqui estão utilizando eles juntos e qual a razão, perguntei e ninguém soube responder! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem o código completo da *procedure*, mas se for só isso, o `SAVE` está sem uso no seu caso.

`SAVE TRANSACTION` salva um ponto no bloco de código para retornar caso seja cancelada a transação (`ROLLBACK`), ou seja, cancela o que foi executado a partir daquele ponto, e não toda a transação.

Um exemplo prático seria o seguinte:

Um determinado processo usa 2 *procedures* para ser completado:
"StoredProcedure1" e "StoredProcedure2".

StoredProcedure1 inicia uma transação com `BEGIN TRANSACTION` e em certo ponto, executa a StoredProcedure2. Imagine que no seu fluxo, caso ocorra um erro na StoredProcedure2, você queira fazer o `ROLLBACK` apenas do que foi executado na StoredProcedure2. Nesse caso, você salva um *checkpoint* na StoredProcedure2, para que seja possível, dentro da mesma transação, fazer o `ROLLBACK` somente daquele *checkpoint*.  Exemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StoredProcedure1 
 ....
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
 ....

 EXEC StoredProcedure2
 ....
 COMMIT
GO
```

E a segunda *procedure*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StoredProcedure2

   -- Verifica se já existe uma transação aberta e salva a informação e o *checkpoint* se necessário
    DECLARE @TranCounter INT;  
    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;

     IF @TranCounter > 0  
        -- se já existir uma transação, salva um checkpoint
        SAVE TRANSACTION Procedure2Checkpoint;  
    ELSE  
        -- senão inicia uma nova
        BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

    ....
    -- em caso de erro, tratado com TRY por exemplo:
      IF @TranCounter = 0  
           -- transação iniciada aqui, rollback de tudo
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
      ELSE  
            -- transação já iniciada antes, em StoreProcedure1, roolback só do que foi executado em StoredProcedure2, a partir do SAVE
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Procedure2Checkpoint; 

GO
```

Veja mais aqui, de onde adaptei esse exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Ah, entendi.. se eu tiver um Save no meio da transacao, significa que naquele ponto mesmo dando rollback depois aquilo foi salvo, correto ?

Comment: Isso, se fizer o roolback com o nome daquele save, dai faz o roolback daquele ponto em diante apenas

Comment: perfeito Ricardo, me ajudou bastante p/ compreender. um abs!